# Vagrant up error : GnuTLS recv error (-9): A TLS packet with unexpected length was received

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-provision

I have installed `Vagrant 1.8.1` in my ubuntu 16. I have virtual box installed too.
while doing vagrant up I am getting error

*An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.
GnuTLS recv error (-9): A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.*

I gone through the other solutions but seems not working for me.
I tried to remove tmp folder of vagrant too. Please advise if someone knows the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gone through many scenarios and finally comes up with solution. which can help other peoples. so I tried change combination of virtualBox version(5.0) and vagrant version (2.2.1), that solved my issue.